# How to load json parsed data only on first run so when i click the tab the listview already populated?

Tags: android, json, listview

I'm using web domain to parsed data and passed it to my android listview. How can i load data only on first run so when i clicked again the tab it will not load again the data from the web and the listview will be populated already? Is it possible?

```
package com.example.work.mcoatorderingapplication;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

 import android.text.Editable;

 import android.text.InputType;

 import android.text.TextWatcher;

 import android.util.Log;

 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
 import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Map;



 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;


public static final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


private static final String GET_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String GET_MESSAGE = "message";

 //FOR ALL PRODUCTS
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> orderlist;
private static final String PRODUCTLIST_URL = "http://alliedpaint-001-site1.smarterasp.net/productlist.php";
private static final String ORDER_URL = "http://alliedpaint-001-site1.smarterasp.net/insertorder.php";
static final String GET_PRODUCT = "message";
static final String GET_ID = "ID";
static final String GET_BRAND = "Brand";
static final String GET_CATEGORY = "Category";
static final String GET_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
static final String GET_CODE = "Code";
static final String GET_QUANTITY = "Quantity";
static final String GET_UNIT = "Unit";
static final String GET_UNITPRICE = "Unitprice";
static final String GET_IMAGE = "Image";
static final String GET_TOTAL = "Total";




ProgressDialog pDialog;
Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
ListViewAdapter ladapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[];
int Numboftabs = 4;
ListView lv,lv1;
ImageLoader imageloader;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    username =getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");
    password =getIntent().getStringExtra("Password");



    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);



    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs=(SlidingTabLayout)

            findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer()

                               {
                                   @Override
                                   public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {


                                       return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);

                                   }
                               }

    );
    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs=(SlidingTabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab, 0);

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        pagelistener.onPageSelected(0);

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    new LoadProducts().execute();
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    new LoadCart().execute();
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    new LoadOrderStatus().execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


    checkconnection= new CheckInternet(getApplicationContext());



}


//LOAD ALL PRODUCTS ON THE FIRST LOAD
final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagelistener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        if(position==0){

            new LoadProducts().execute();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};





private void updateproductlist() {



    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewproduct);
    ladapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, orderlist);
    listview.setAdapter(ladapter);

    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {


        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                       int posistion, long id) {

            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);


            final String Quantity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Quantity)).getText().toString();
            final String Brand = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Brand)).getText().toString();
            final String Category = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Category)).getText().toString();
            final String Code = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Code)).getText().toString();
            final String Description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Description)).getText().toString();
            final String Unit = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Unit)).getText().toString();
            final String Price = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Price)).getText().toString();

            class InsertOrder extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                boolean failure = false;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Moving to Cart...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                    int success;

                    try {

                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Quantity", input.getText().toString()));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Brand", Brand));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Category", Category));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Code", Code));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Description", Description));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Unit", Unit));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Unitprice", Price));


                        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                ORDER_URL, "POST", params);


                        success = json.getInt(GET_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 0) {

                            return json.getString(GET_MESSAGE);
                        } else {
                            return json.getString(GET_MESSAGE);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog1
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dia1log once product deleted
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    if (file_url != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            alert.setTitle("Enter Quantity");
            alert.setView(input);
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

            input.setText(Quantity);

            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    if (input.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Quantity first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else {
                            new InsertOrder().execute();

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });
            alert.show();

            return true;

        }

    });

}


public void UpdateJsonProduct(){


    orderlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(PRODUCTLIST_URL);


try {


    order = json.getJSONArray(GET_PRODUCT);

    for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject c = order.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = c.getString(GET_ID);

        String brand = c.getString(GET_BRAND);

        String category = c.getString(GET_CATEGORY);

        String code = c.getString(GET_CODE);

        String description = c.getString(GET_DESCRIPTION);

        String quantity = c.getString(GET_QUANTITY);

        String unit = c.getString(GET_UNIT);

        String unitprice = c.getString(GET_UNITPRICE);

        String image = c.getString(GET_IMAGE);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put(GET_ID,id);

        map.put(GET_BRAND, brand);

        map.put(GET_CATEGORY, category);

        map.put(GET_CODE, code);

        map.put(GET_DESCRIPTION, description);

        map.put(GET_QUANTITY, quantity);

        map.put(GET_UNIT, unit);

        map.put(GET_UNITPRICE, unitprice);

        map.put(GET_IMAGE,image);

        orderlist.add(map);

    }

     } catch (JSONException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

 }

 }



final  public class LoadProducts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        pDialog.setCancelable(true);

        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        UpdateJsonProduct();

        return null;

    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        pDialog.dismiss();

        updateproductlist();

    }


 }





 }
```

Comment: Create a Boolean variable and set it true when you load the data, and load the data only when that variable is false

Comment: @Santiago can you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this variable

```
boolean isDataLoaded = false;
```

Your onPageSelected method would be:

```
@Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        if(position==0){

        if(!isDataLoaded)
            new LoadProducts().execute();
        }

    }
```

And update variable isDataLoaded to true when you populate listview correctly in your PostExecute of LoadProducts Asynctask:

```
    updateproductlist();

    isDataLoaded = true;
```

Or in your method updateproductlist, you can decide

Comment: when i put that code in post execute i get an error Cannot assign a value to final variable.

Comment: try only boolean isDataLoaded = false; without private final